# How do I use setmqauth to turn off setall

Tags: ibm-mq

I am on Linux and am trying to test context authority, where I am/am not allowed up update applname in the mqmd.
With 'testuser' I can do this using -setall or +setall

*setmqaut -m QMA -n CP0000 -t queue  -p testuser -setall*

With my main userid ( in group mqm) I am always allowed to do this, and cannot make it fail.

*dmpmqaut -m QMA -n CP0000  -t queue   -p colinpaice -e*
gives

```
profile:     CP0000
object type: queue
entity:      mqm
entity type: group
authority:   get browse put inq set dlt chg dsp passid passall setid clr
- - - - - - - -
profile:     CP0000
object type: queue
entity:      colinpaice
entity type: group
authority:   get browse inq set dlt chg dsp passid passall setid clr
- - - - - - - -
profile:     @class
object type: queue
entity:      colinpaice
entity type: group
authority:   crt
- - - - - - - -
profile:     @class
object type: queue
entity:      mqm
entity type: group
authority:   crt*
```

And there is no setall specified.

Even if I issue
*setmqaut -m QMA -n CP0000   -t queue   -p colinpaice -setall*
then
*dspmqaut -m QMA -n CP0000   -t queue   -p colinpaice*
has setall in the list.

Im sure this must be something obvious - but I cannot see it.

*dspmqaut -m QMA   -t qmgr   -p colinpaice*
does not have setall in the list.

Is there another switch I need to toggle?

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking how to remove an authority from a user that is in the mqm group?

Comment: yes.   I want the userid to be able to define queues etc.. but not change the message context of messages on a queue.

Comment: https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=authority-authorizations-context says _Authorizations for context.: setall  Set all context on the specified queue_,  It doesnt say "privileged or setall" which is what I suspect it should say.

Comment: "` -p colinpaice -setall` then `dspmqaut -m QMA -n CP0000 -t queue -p colinpaice` has setall in the list"  do you mean +setall?

Comment: It reported stuff like get put **setall**

Answer (score 0):

I found how to do it...
It looks like being in mqm group trumps other checks, and gives you authority to do anything.

I removed my userid from group mqm, and used the runmqsc command *refresh security* and the request to use applname worked as expected ( I could turn enable/disable using setmqauth +setall|-setall )
Adding my id back into the group and using the refresh security again  gave me my original behavior.

Comment: With 9.2 you can set the application name presented to MQ in distributed APIs (C, .Net, etc) this would carry over to the MQMD, in effect you can set the applname without setall. Java/JMS had this feature from 7.5, and if course you can always rename an executable.